# Use scope variable in attributes of HTML tags

Tags: css, angularjs, scope

I want to assign font-size based on the scope value,

I tried something like this

```
<td data-ng-repeat="dataColumn in data track by $index" data-ng-class="[dataColumn.properties.textalign, dataColumn.properties.width]" style="font-size:{{dataColumn.properties.textsize - 1}}+px;">
```

this is working fine in chrome but not in internet explorer,

Anything wrong with this?

Comment: What version of IE are you talking about?

Comment: version - Internet explorer 10

Comment: why not to use ng-style?

Comment: @AmitChoukroune ng-style does not support !important.

Comment: @satishkumarV watch caitp comment. basically you shouldn't use important in tag attribute but if it's essential you can use `ng-attr-style`
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5379/#issuecomment-30403765

Answer (score 3):

according to angular js
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

> To ensure your Angular application works on IE please consider:
>
> Use `ng-style` tags instead of `style="{{ someCss }}"`. The latter works in Chrome and Firefox but does not work in Internet Explorer <= 11 (the most recent version at time of writing).